The state and classes do not change in ReactJS
App.jsx:
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate  } from 'react-router-dom'
import Leaderboard from './pages/Leaderboard'
import About from './pages/About'
import Scoresfeed from './pages/Scores-feed'
import Header from './components/Header/Header'
import './App.css'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header/>
      <Routes>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/scores-feed" element={<Scoresfeed />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/leaderboard" />} />
          <Route path="/leaderboard" element={<Leaderboard />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;


Header.jsx:
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Header.css';

const Header = () => {
    const [isNavOpen, setIsNavOpen] = useState(false);
    const navRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleOutsideClick = (event) => {
            if (navRef.current && !navRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
                setIsNavOpen(false);
            }
        };

        document.addEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick);
        };
    }, [isNavOpen]);

    const handleNavToggle = () => {
        setIsNavOpen((isNavOpen) => !isNavOpen);
    };

    return (
        <header className="header">
            <div className="nav-toggle" onClick={handleNavToggle}>
                <svg
                    width="24"
                    height="24"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    fill="none"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    strokeWidth="2"
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    strokeLinejoin="round"
                    className={`feather feather-chevron-down ${isNavOpen ? 'open' : ''}`}
                >
                    <polyline points="6 9 12 15 18 9"></polyline>
                </svg>
                <span className={`nav-toggle-label ${isNavOpen ? 'hidden' : ''}`}>Open navigation</span>
            </div>
            <nav ref={navRef} className={`nav ${isNavOpen ? 'open' : ''}`}>
                <ul className="nav-list">
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link to="/leaderboard">
                            <svg
                                width="140"
                                height="50"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                viewBox="0 0 200 50"
                                preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
                                className="svg-icon"
                            >
                                <rect x="5" y="40" width="5" height="5" fill="none" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="2" />
                                <rect x="180" y="5" width="5" height="5" fill="none" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="2" />
                                <line x1="1" y1="12" x2="12" y2="1" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="2" />
                                <line x1="179" y1="49" x2="190" y2="37" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="2" />
                                <polygon points="20,0 190,0 190,30 172,50 0,50 0,40 0,20" fill="none" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="3" className="svg-border" />
                                <text className='text' x="50%" y="50%" textAnchor="middle" fill="white" dy=".3em" fontSize="30">Leaderboard</text>
                            </svg>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link to="/scores-feed">
                            <svg
                                width="140"
                                height="50"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                viewBox="0 0 200 50"
                                preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
                                className="svg-icon"
                            >
                                <rect x="5" y="40" width="5" height="5" fill="none" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="2" />
                                <rect x="180" y="5" width="5" height="5" fill="none" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="2" />
                                <line x1="1" y1="12" x2="12" y2="1" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="2" />
                                <line x1="179" y1="49" x2="190" y2="37" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="2" />
                                <polygon points="20,0 190,0 190,30 172,50 0,50 0,40 0,20" fill="none" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="3" className="svg-border" />
                                <text className='text' x="50%" y="50%" textAnchor="middle" fill="white" dy=".3em" fontSize="30">Scores feed</text>
                            </svg>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link to="/about">
                            <svg
                                width="140"
                                height="50"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                viewBox="0 0 200 50"
                                preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
                                className="svg-icon"
                            >
                                <rect x="5" y="40" width="5" height="5" fill="none" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="2" />
                                <rect x="180" y="5" width="5" height="5" fill="none" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="2" />
                                <line x1="1" y1="12" x2="12" y2="1" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="2" />
                                <line x1="179" y1="49" x2="190" y2="37" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="2" />
                                <polygon points="20,0 190,0 190,30 172,50 0,50 0,40 0,20" fill="none" stroke="rgb(19, 65, 150)" strokeWidth="3" className="svg-border" />
                                <text className='text' x="50%" y="50%" textAnchor="middle" fill="white" dy=".3em" fontSize="30">About</text>
                            </svg>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    );
};

export default Header;


I have a component that needs to render a header. Inside it there is a svg “button” that should be toggled, thereby changing the state and adding/removing classes so that the menu is shown. But for some reason this doesn't happen.
But if I change the state directly through React DevTools, then the menu appears:


I tried changing the dependencies in useEffect but it didn't help. Classes are simply not added, and the state does not change. Please tell me what is the reason for my mistake

Do you need to use the ref? Since it works normally if you remove ref and useEffect. Your issue is basically the condition inside handleOutsideClick since every time you set  isNavOpen to anything the useEffect gets triggered and sets it back to false.

@Dustaboy3 it doesn’t do that. Quite contrary, it just adds another event listener to document. The handler is recreated each time and then added to document. Also useEffect() invokes the effect function once on first render and then again and again each time isNavOpen is mutated. If you understood this comment but still need an answer, I’ll write one.

Аfter 12 hours I solved the problem like this:
const [isNavOpen, setIsNavOpen] = useState(false);
const navRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const handleOutsideClick = (event) => {
        if (navRef.current && !navRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
            console.log('Clicked outside, closing navigation');
            setIsNavOpen(false);
        }
    };

    document.addEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick);

    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick);
    };
}, []);

const handleNavToggle = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Toggling navigation, current state:', isNavOpen);
    setIsNavOpen((prev) => {
        console.log('New state:', !prev);
        return !prev;
    });
};

console.log('Rendering component, isNavOpen:', isNavOpen);


that looks like you're going to be stacking eventlisteners anytime isNavOpen is updated you'll add another listener, probably just removing isNavOpen from the dependency array could help, you only want to bind the eventlistener once on mount
useEffect(() => {
    const handleOutsideClick = (event) => {
        if (navRef.current && !navRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
            setIsNavOpen(false);
        }
    };

    document.addEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick);

    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick);
    };
// just bind the event listen once on mount
}, []);


I tried it, but it didn't help
